# Product PDF attachment - Attribute with Multiple Files

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have created a product attribute called product_downloads, I can put a file name there and it appears in the product view page in the tab "Additional Information" with a link to the file name. I have successfully implemented this idea for one download, but for some products I will have multiple downloads...

Like I said, I have the code working with one download per product, all that took was a small amount of code inside of app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

Where the original code was:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is the code I have replaced that with:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<?php if ((string)$_data['value'] != '' and $_data['value'] != 'N/A'): ?>   <!-- IF NOTHING DO NOTHING-->
<tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <?php if ($_data['code'] == 'product_download'): ?>
        <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "media/downloads/{$_product->getProductDownload()}";?>">Product PDF</a>
        </td>
        <?php else: ?>          
                <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works perfectly, however... What I need now is to look at the value of product_download, if it has a comma(or some other divider, if this would interfere with a csv format) make two separate links to two seperate files..

One major thing to note... I rely heavily on MAGMI, which is why I have taken this route as no extension allows me to massively import attachments to products.

This is for spec sheets and such... some products have multiple spec sheets. I want to use a single attribute to store multiple file names and have code that will differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use logic with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function And change your if condition with my custom code as below

```
<?php if ($_data['code'] == 'product_download'): ?>
<?php
$product_downloads = explode(",",$_product->getProductDownload());

foreach($product_downloads as $download):
?>
        <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "media/downloads/{$download}";?>">Product PDF</a>
        </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>          
                <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

this is just logic you can use as per your thoughts as well.

hope this will sure help you.